# Xamarin API to read audio jack input ( like Square CC reader ) & bluetooth connectivity?

Tags: xamarin, monodevelop, monotouch.dialog

Does Xamarin has API to read audio jack input ( like Square CC reader ) & bluetooth connectivity?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin provides wrappers around the native platform APIs.  If Android or iOS has a native API to do X, then Xamarin should provide an API to do it too.

[Xamarin.Android Bluetooth Sample](http://developer.xamarin.com/samples/android/Bluetooth/)

[Xamarin.iOS Bluetooth Sample](http://developer.xamarin.com/samples/AirLocate/)

I'm not sure how Square and other devices interface over the headphone jack.  I imagine they just process raw audio input somehow - you should be able to do the same via the Xamarin APIs.

Comment: He would probably have to create C# bindings to their native library (unless it has already been done) which implements the audio decoding algorithm they use.